# How to do REPLACE on mySQL at the beginning and end of text?

Tags: mysql, concatenation, replace

I am trying to wrap a block of text in post_content column in wp_posts table with custom tags. Now, what I know for sure is that all the blocks of text (hundreds) that I need to apply this to look like the following:

```
blah blah blah...
<!--more-->
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
```

and I need that to look like this instead:

```
blah blah blah...
[custom_tag]
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
[/custom_tag]
```

Can that be done in mySQL somehow using REPLACE command, or some sort of concatenation in addition to replace? Any ideas?

Comment: You'd be better off fetching the data from MySQL, reading it with an HTML parser, performing the desired manipulations (e.g. to the DOM), serialising the result and storing it back in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
concat(replace(s,'<!--more-->','[custom_tag]'),'[/custom_tag]')
```

or if you need insert `[custom_tag]` before the `<script`

```
concat(replace(s,'<script','[custom_tag] <script'),'[/custom_tag]')
```